# Dúvida aplicação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Laravel em uma hospedagem da HostGator, mas o caminha de acesso da página de entrada (a index) é o seguinte:

http://www.meusite.com/projeto1/public/

Como faço para que o conteúdo do site (bem como todos os arquivos e diretório sequentes) sejam encontrados a partir de em http://www.meusite.com/?